# Can Kickstart/Preseed install more than 1 OS

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, preseed, kickstart

I need to have a dual boot system, both OS will be Ubuntu.

Is it possible to have kickstart/preseed install more than one OS? For example kickstart/preseed install Ubuntu on sdaX and sdaY on the same server?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit off. Kickstart is not what is used to install a system, it is what is used during the install to skip questions during the install. So it can not possibly be used to create a dual boot since that is a whole different level. For you to install 2 Ubuntu's on 1 system the installer needs to be able to do that. And it can't.

If you want to automate a dual boot install you need 2 installation media each with 1 kickstart file designed for that specific install (ie. it will have 2 different targets to install to).

For installing multiple operating systems you would use a PXE server but even then you are limited to 1 kickstart file: the idea is to create multiple identical installations.

Comment: Thanks. You can see why the question wasn't off, i needed to explain my installation method so you can see how im going about it. Currently i am using kickstart to create another partition. So i install Ubuntu on sdaX and then create sdaY. Then using dd i am cloning sdaX to sdaY. I change grub, fstab etc and can mount sdaY from within sdaX and see the OS, however i cannot boot into sdaY as i get a kernel panic error. Any ideas?